# Formalize $\intop_{0}^{1}f(x)\text{d}x$ For a Rather Odd "Step" Function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

> Define $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $f(0)=0$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{10^n},
> > x\in\mathcal{I}_{k}=\left(\frac{1}{2^{n+1}},\frac{1}{2^{n}}\right]$
>   where $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Prove that $f$ is integrable on $[0,1]$
>   and calculate $\int_0^1 f$.

Okay so what I did first is to prove it's monotonic (nondecreasing) hence integrable which I'm pretty sure I got to prove (but I assumed $\bigcap_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{I}_{k}=\emptyset$ and  $\bigcup_{k=0}^{\infty}\mathcal{I}_{k}=(0,1]$). Now I want to formalize the calculation itself and This is what I had in mind

$$\intop_{0}^{1}f(x)\text{d}x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\intop_{\mathcal{I}_{k}}f(x)\text{d}x=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\intop_{\frac{1}{2^{k+1}}}^{\frac{1}{2^{k}}}\frac{1}{10^{k}}\text{d}x= \underbrace{\cdots}_{\text{easy}} =\frac{10}{19}$$

But I think that further justification is needed for the 1st and 2nd equalities. I know that the value at $x=0$ isn't supposed to change $\int_0^1 f$ but it feels wierd that I'm not including it within the calculation without explaining exactly why.

It's also odd to me that my integration on the **open** interval $\left(\frac{1}{2^{k+1}},\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right]$ became integration on the closed interval $\left[\frac{1}{2^{k+1}},\frac{1}{2^{k}}\right]$. I couldn't really explain how I did it and it feels very fishy.

So as you can see I think I already did most of the work, but I do need to help in the refining final steps.

Comment: If you want to prove that something is integrable, you probably should use the upper/lower sums definition of integrability.

Comment: As I said I already proved its integrable since the function is nondecreasing. This is not why I asked help!

Comment: It is Riemann integrable. Just compute the upper or lower sum using a partition. You are right. Interchanging limit and integral often needs an argument.

Comment: I don't totally disagree, but I think some care needs to be taken because this function has infinitely many discontinuities. Does your theorem say that *any* monotone function is integrable? (It's true, but you might want to check that it isn't for finite discontinuities.)

Comment: @user251257 So you want me to apply a Riemann sum to this function for some partition $P$, after proving its intergable, and let the $\lambda(P)\rightarrow 0$ hoping the sum will converge to $\frac{10}{19}$?. But which partition should I choose?

Comment: @CameronWilliams I don't think the proof in my book assumes its continious, I can apply it for any function.

Comment: @Theorem well ... the question is very suggestive...

Comment: @user251257 Obviously the first idea that pops up to mind is to take points of the form $\frac{1}{2^k}$ but then $\lambda(P)$ won't approach 0.

Comment: @CameronWilliams the set of discontinuity is at most countable...

Comment: @Theorem how you divide an interval $I_n$ (you have here a typo) is not important, as $f$ is constant on such an interval.

Comment: So beside diving $[0,1]$ by points of the form $\frac{1}{2^k}$, I also divide each gap between them to $n$ equal pieces for instance (And because the biggest gap is of length $\frac{1}{2}$ then $\lambda(P)=\frac{1}{2n}$)? Isn't that a bit of an overkill?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do that elementary.

Consider the partition $P_0 = \{I_0, [0,1]\setminus I_0 \}$.
Then, the upper sum is
$$ U_0 = |I_0|\sup_{x\in I_0} f(x) + (1-|I_0|)\sup_{x\in [0,1]\setminus I_0} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 1 = 1 $$
and the lower sum is
$$ L_0 = |I_0|\inf_{x\in I_0} f(x) + (1-|I_0|)\inf_{x\in [0,1]\setminus I_0} = \frac{1}{2}\cdot 1 + \frac{1}{2} \cdot 0 = \frac{1}{2}. $$

Now, consider $P_n = \{I_0,\dotsc, I_n, [0,1]\setminus I_n \}$. Can you guess the upper and lower sum according to $P_n$? What are their limits?

Now, to ensure that the mesh of the partition converge to zero: Can you divide say $I_m$ into $2^{n-m}$ intervals of length $\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}$, for $m \le n$?

Comment: Ah so you're using Darboux definition and not Reimann's one! But what bothers me is that you took the upper/lower sum of SOME partition $P_n$. You may show that as $n\rightarrow\infty$ these 2 sums converge to $\frac{10}{19}$ but Darboux's definition requires to take the upper and lower integrals, meaning the $\sup$/$\inf$ of ALL possible upper/lower sums of ALL partitions, and show they're equal.

$EDIT$: Nevermind! It now occured to me that I have a theorem to deal just with your type of situation! I will try this out then.

Comment: @Theorem: well both definitions are the same ... you can make the same argue with Riemann's definition. I've added a hint to the answer.

Comment: @Theorem: btw. the upper integral is the **infimum** of all upper sums and the lower integral is **supremum** of all lower sums. Now, what can you say about the infimum of all upper sums comparing to a particular upper sum?

Comment: Okay after some work I think I've managed to do it. I took the partition $P_{n}=\left\{ 0,\frac{1}{2^{n}},\dots,\frac{1}{2^{2}},\frac{1}{2^{1}},\frac{1}{2^{0}}\right\}$ as you said and showed $S(P_{n})=\frac{1}{10^{n}2^{n}}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{10^{k}2^{k}}$ and $s(P_{n})=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{10^{k}2^{k}}$. Hence $S(P_n)-s(P_n)=\frac{1}{20^n}$ approaches 0 and thus I conclude from a theorem that $f$ is integrable and its integral is $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s(P_n)=\frac{10}{19}$. Am I correct?

Comment: @Theorem: yes. There are obviously more ways to solve this problem, it was just my first idea.

Comment: Can't thank you enough! Though I am curious to see how other ways work out (including my initial solution) I won't since I nagged you too much already. :P

Comment: @Theorem: there are theorems which allow you to interchange limits and integrals. These are presented usually later.